# How to resolve Ruby on Rails ImageMagick conflict?

Tags: 10.04, configuration, ruby, rails

I am trying to install [refinerycms](http://refinerycms.com/), a Ruby on Rails CMS on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. I run `rails server` and I get the following exception:

```
carcher@carcher-laptop:~/Code/tgc$ rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.0.0 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.12.2/lib/RMagick2.so: This installation of RMagick was configured with ImageMagick 6.6.4 but ImageMagick 6.5.7-8 is in use. (RuntimeError)
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:591:in `new_constants_in'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.12.2/lib/RMagick.rb:11
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:591:in `new_constants_in'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/dragonfly-0.7.6/lib/dragonfly/analysis/r_magick_analyser.rb:1
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/dragonfly-0.7.6/lib/dragonfly/config/r_magick.rb:15:in `apply_configuration'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/dragonfly-0.7.6/lib/dragonfly/configurable.rb:33:in `configure'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/dragonfly-0.7.6/lib/dragonfly/config/r_magick.rb:14:in `apply_configuration'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/dragonfly-0.7.6/lib/dragonfly/configurable.rb:39:in `configure_with'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/refinerycms-0.9.8.2/vendor/refinerycms/images/lib/images.rb:10
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `run_initializers'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `send'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
 from /home/carcher/Code/tgc/config/environment.rb:5
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:591:in `new_constants_in'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
 from /home/carcher/Code/tgc/config.ru:3
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
 from /home/carcher/Code/tgc/config.ru:1:in `new'
 from /home/carcher/Code/tgc/config.ru:1
carcher@carcher-laptop:~/Code/tgc$
```

I built and installed ImageMagick 6.6.4 from source following the instructions [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php#unix) and BEFORE I did that I removed the ImageMagick tools that were pre-installed in Ubuntu, to avoid any conflicts. But still I seem to have this version 6.5.7 around.

I guess my question is how do I remove/disable `ImageMagick 6.5.7-8`?

Comment: Is it possible the version number just exists in a config file somehwere? Also, did you `apt-get purge` imagemagick or just `apt-get remove`?

Comment: I removed it via the Ubuntu Software Center, not through the shell. In fact if I run `sudo apt-get purge imagemagick` now it tells me it's not installed! I did install it though from source as I mentioned. How can I find and purge that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm up and running! Solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712121/imagemagick-conflict-on-ubuntu-running-webbrick) on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely you installed imagemagick 6.5.7 to /usr/local, if you can't find it in your package listing.

Try `which convert` to see where imagemagick binaries are located. (`convert` is one of the utilities shipped with imagemagick.) Also try `convert --version` to see which version is active. If you get a different version than what Ruby/Rails is seeing, check your project configuration to make sure you don't have any extra paths it may be looking in. Also, be sure that imagemagick wasn't installed to your Rails app directory; I think it may try to include things there as well.

Comment: No joy - `convert --version` returns 6.5.7, and no sign of problems with the project files. Gonna try a clean install I think.

Comment: In that case, try *installing* the version in the archives (`aptitude install --reinstall imagemagick`) and then remove it again. That should clean it out, I think, depending on where it's located. Was it in /usr/bin/convert when running `which convert`?